How to create a second Super Admin or Super User via MySQL DB
I have the super user, but I use a plugin that currently does not support me where only the Super Admin can delete some data. I want to be able to create a second super admin without having to transform the site into a multisite so that this second one can manage part of the site. I will control the limitations with Menu editor pro URE. Could anyone tell me if it is possible to create a second SuperAdmin using the Wordpress user environment along with changes into the mysql db?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
